# Angular, Flask, mysql.connector ProgrammingError: Wrong number of arguments

Tags: python, mysql, angularjs, flask

I'm using Angular, Flask and MySQL.connector to connect to a MySQL database:

This is my python flask code handling post requests inserting a new "movie":

```
@app.route("/addMovies", methods=['POST'])
def addMovies():
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', database='MovieTheatre')
    cursor = cnx.cursor()
    insert_stmt = (
        "INSERT INTO Movie (idMovie, MovieName, MovieYear) "
        "VALUES (%d, %s, %d)"
    )

    post = request.get_json()
    #data = (post['idMovie'], post['MovieName'], post['MovieYear'])
    data = (100, 'Test', 2010) # test data 
    print(insert_stmt,data)
    cursor.execute(insert_stmt,data)
    cnx.commit()
    cnx.close()
    return data
```

I know its not my Angularjs, because my browser console says Internal Server Error (500) so I started printing out the insert statement handled by flask and mysql.connector:

```
('INSERT INTO Movie (idMovie, MovieName, MovieYear) VALUES (%d, %s, %d)', (100, 'Test', 2010))
```

Which seems correct.

However I keep getting

```
    "Wrong number of arguments during string formatting")
ProgrammingError: Wrong number of arguments during string formatting
```

===============================================================================

Thanks to the answers, its fixed, for those wondering this is what I switched my code to :

```
@app.route("/addMovies", methods=['POST'])
def addMovies():
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', database='MovieTheatre')
    cursor = cnx.cursor()
    insert_stmt = (
        "INSERT INTO Movie (idMovie, MovieName, MovieYear) "
        "VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
    )

    post = request.get_json()
    data = (post['idMovie'], post['MovieName'], post['MovieYear'])
    print(insert_stmt,data)
    cursor.execute(insert_stmt,data)
    cnx.commit()
    cnx.close()
    return data
```

Comment: you don't even need to call str() manually since the type conversion is the task of the cursor.execute method

Comment: ok true will remove that then

Comment: however then i get this error: 
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html), it says the cursor.execute() method converts things as necessary to something the database understands. It seems you are supposed to use only `%s` placeholders in your string and let everything else on the execute method.

Answer (score 1):

SQL parameter substitution is not the same as string formatting. You should always use `%s`, even for integers.